# How to display all line before and after string matches until blank line detected in shell

Tags: bash, unix

I need an help to `grep` a file which has lot of data.  I have a file with below line:

```
random line with hashcode 1
This file is use for some analysis
Analysis code is <01234>
This is line after analysis

This is second test line
This file is use for some analysis
Analysis code is <01234>
This is line after analysis

Some data to be here as well 
This file is use for some analysis
Analysis code is <01267>
This is line after analysis
```

I wanted to print only those line which have string "Analysis code" with value "01234" and print all line before and after it.
I have tried to get the solution half way but need complete logic.

```
egrep -i "Analysis code" c.txt |
grep -i 01234 |
awk -F "<" '{print $2}' |
awk -F ">" '{print $1}' |
uniq > am.txt
while read line ; do
    echo $line
    awk "/$line/,/$^/" c.txt
done <am.txt
```

After this, I am getting output only starting from the line having the analysis code.

I wanted to print all lines before the matching string up until blank line appears on the top:

```
random line with hashcode 1
This file is use for some analysis
Analysis code is <01234>
This is line after analysis

This is second test line
This file is use for some analysis
Analysis code is <01234>
This is line after analysis
```

Comment: How about: `awk -v RS="" -v ORS="\n\n" -v IGNORECASE=1 '/analysis code/ && /01234/' am.txt`.

Comment: Thanks tshiono. It worked and this is what I am looking for. You have saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using grep option to print lines before and after matching line:

```
    grep c.txt -e "Analysis code.*<01234>" -B2 -A1
```

If you want to print a paragraph that is separated by an empty line a multiline pattern can be used or awk like this:

`awk -v RS='' '/Analysis code.*<01234>/' c.txt`

Comment: You mean uppercase `-A` and `-B`.

Comment: you are right @tripleee. It is fixed, thanks

Comment: Should the `-B1 -A2` instead be `-B2 -A1`?

Comment: it is a right amendment